# Trying to run bash command with subprocess.run but not successfull

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

Im trying to create a python bash script to launch web client. Im using subprocess.run to run that command but not successful yet after so many tries. My executable file is of type (.out) and placed in directory /opt/client/linuxclientd/bin/. It takes two arguments and runs with command "sudo ./client.out username password" when you are in the same directory. Following python script i have tried so far and not doing job correctly

```
import os
import subprocess

os.chdir('/opt/client/linuxclientd/bin/') #to get into the directory where app is installed
subprocess.run(['sudo', 'service', 'clientd', 'start'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE) #to start service
client = subprocess.run(['sudo', './client.out', 'username', 'password'], timeout =10, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = client.stdout.decode('utf-8')
print(output)
```

The problem is that script starts the service then hangs out without doing anything and i get time out exception after 10 seconds. It means script is unable to run "sudo', './client.out', 'username', 'password'" command and thus my headless client is not launched.

Any help or suggestion of doing it in better way would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is not working ? What is the error(if any) you are getting ?

Comment: did you try running your script with sudo as well ?

Comment: You indicated binary is in /opt/myyapp/bin/client.out, but your script perform 'chdir' to /opt/invisily/linuxclientd/bin). Did you set PATH to include /opt/myapp/bin ? Alternatively, include full path to './client.out'

Comment: I added my problem statement above. Also, im running this script with sudo. Can you please confirm where and how to add PATH. May be thats the point which is causing problem.

Comment: Consider changing 'client = subprocess.run(['sudo', './client.out', ' to include full path to your client.out: 'client = subprocess.run('sudo', ' /opt/client/linuxclientd/bin/client.out', ...)

Comment: I get this error on adding full path "libspa.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". I believe this executable on runs with ./client.out :(